# Enable and Disable Crittercism dynamically

Tags: android, crittercism

We recently started using Crittercism for Android (crittercism_v5_3_0_ndk). We have found a issue in enabling and disabling Crittercism in app dynamically using `setOptOutStatus()` api. This setting is reflected only on next launch of the app and not in current session of the app. We  checked this using `getOptOutStatus()` api and it does not return the recent setting made using `setOptOutStatus()`.

Can you let me know if there is any known issue with this or any specific usage pattern need to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I signaled this issue on january 2015 to Crittercism support. It's only on Crittercism for Android; it works fine on iOS sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your Crittercism jar or gradle dependency and it should work. This was fixed in Sep 2015 in Crittercism SDK 5.3.4 according to

http://docs.crittercism.com/release_notes/release_notes_android.html#version-5-3-4-sep-22-2015